# Z3 behaviour if inapplicable tactic is used?

Tags: z3

What is Z3's behavior in general if a tactic is applied that aught not be appropriate to the specific problem?  For example:

```
(declare-fun x () Real)
(declare-fun y () Real)
(assert (= x (* y y)))
(check-sat-using qflia)
```

This specific example returns `sat`. I'm surprised by this, because the problem is not in `QFLIA`. I would have expected either an error, or `unknown`.

Is it safe to apply a tactic even if you don't know whether the tactic you're applying is actually applicable to the specific problem instance?

Answer (score 0):

Issuing `(help-tactic)` over the SMT-LIB 2 API gives a huge amount of information about the different built-in tactics and the options they support.  Somewhere in there, you'll find:

```
- qflia builtin strategy for solving QF_LIA problems.
    add_bound_lower (rational) (default: -2) lower bound to be added to unbounded variables.
    add_bound_upper (rational) (default: 2) upper bound to be added to unbounded variables.
    ...
    fail_if_inconclusive (bool) (default: true) fail if found unsat (sat) for under (over) approximated goal.
```

An interesting parameter here is `fail_if_inconclusive`. As I understand it, this parameter means that, when using under-approximations such as `add_bound_lower`, `unsat` results will be converted to `unknown`.  In fact, it seems to be impossible to get an `unsat` result when `add_bounds` is used.

I am not sure about this, but it seems that applying the `qflia` tactic to a goal not in `QFLIA` may also be treated as an under-approximation.  This is less clear-cut than when using `add-bounds`, because really trivial unsat goals do indeed return `unsat` with qflia, even though they're outside `QFLIA`.  For example, this returns `unsat`:

```
(declare-fun x () Real)
(assert (distinct x x))
(assert (= (* x x) 2.0))
(check-sat-using (using-params qflia :fail_if_inconclusive true))
```

My guess for the reason behind this surprising result is that probably `(distinct x x)` is enough to make the whole goal unsatisfiable in a preprocessing step.

Overall the strategy API seems to work as follows: it may be that useful results are obtained by using a seemingly inappropriate tactic, if that tactic includes an over or under approximation of the goal.  If the goal becomes unsat or sat due to a mismatch between the tactic and the goal, then Z3 will fail (return unknown).